# Permission Denied Error Showing while querying to specific data source in Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-superset

I am trying to access BigQuery from apache-superset. 
I have multiple datasets in Big Query but I want to give permission to a specific dataset for a specific user role.

I have added to a specific dataset and schema the required permission in Superset. However, I'm still getting the following error:

```
You need access to the following tables: ['dataset.table'],   
all database access or `all_datasource_access` permission
```

Comment: Are you getting the same error after you log in to BigQuery console with the user Role and run the query against the dataset with permission?

Comment: No, I can query from Big Query

Comment: What permissions and to what objects have you already granted?